# ¿Como filtrar y paginar con vue.js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Trabajo Laravel 5.8 y Vue2

Tengo un componente vue que recibe datos desde un prop mediante blade.

Necesito paginar estos datos y al mismo tiempo poder filtarlos, inicialmente la paginacion la realice con el metodo paginate de lado de laravel, enviaba los datos al componente y podia paginar sin problemas, pero a la hora de filtar con computed properties (vue) solo me filtraba los datos de la pagina actual y no los demas del resto de la paginación, que deberia hacer para poder filtar eficientemente?

**Actualización**

Metodo get de laravel que trae los datos

```
public function getProperties() {

    $properties = Property::where('state', '=', 1)
    ->with('location','propertyType')
    ->orderByRaw('LENGTH(id)')
    ->paginate(18);
    return [
        'pagination' => [
            'total' => $properties->total(),
            'current_page' => $properties->currentPage(),
            'per_page' => $properties->perPage(),
            'last_page' => $properties->lastPage(),
            'from' => $properties->firstItem(),
            'to' => $properties->lastPage()
        ],
        'properties' => $properties
    ];
}
```

Codigo Js

```
props: ['data'],
    data() {
        return {
            properties: this.data.properties.data,
            errors: null,
            idFlag: null,
            pagination: this.data.pagination,
            search: ''
        }
    },

    computed: {
        isActived: function() {
            return this.pagination.current_page;
        },
        pagesNumber: function() {
            if(!this.pagination.to) {
                return [];
            }

            let from = this.pagination.current_page - 2;

            if(from < 1) {
                from = 1;
            }

            let to = from + (2 * 2);

            if(to >= this.pagination.last_page) {
                to = this.pagination.last_page;
            }

            let pagesArray= [];

            while(from <= to) {
                pagesArray.push(from);
                from++;
            }

            return pagesArray;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        changePage: function(page) {
            this.pagination.current_page = page;

            window.location.href = "./properties?page="+page;
        },

        filterProperties: function() {
            return this.properties.filter((property)=> property.name.includes(this.search))
        }

    },
```

Comment: Lo que estes haciendo para filtrar debes hacerlo para el data completo no solo para el que estas mostrando en la pagina actual.

Comment: Si no es mucho pedir pon tu data y los computed que estas usando para la paginación y para filtrar para poder basado en eso indicarte mejor el camino.

Comment: Hice una actualización con lo que me dijiste